# Solved tangent and normal equation to a curve (verification)

Tags: curves, tangent-line

Now I solved this equation of a curve $4x^3+4xy+y^2=4$ at (0,2) and got the equation of tangent $y=2-2x$ am correct? Yeah
But the question took a different turn to find the coordinates of a further point of intersection which I'm unable to solve till now. Really need help on this!

Comment: Solve $4x^3+4x(2-2x)+(2-2x)^2=4$ for $x$.

Comment: @MichaelUmande You have $y=2-2x$ from what you said.

Comment: On the tangent, $y=2-2x$, surely?

Comment: on which point are you facing the problem?

Comment: isn't the other point of intersection $(1,0)$?

Comment: @toby mark million thanks. I get it now